# Swift: Alert saying it’s blocked when the user visits a URL that isn’t allowed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

Given the code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        if let host = url?.host {
          for website in websites {
            if host.contains(website) {
              decisionHandler(.allow)
              return
            }
          }
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
      }
```

I wrote the following block of code, but it didn’t work correctly no matter where I put it.

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Page blocked!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
 ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
 present(ac, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        if let host = url?.host {
          for website in websites {
            if host.contains(website) {
              decisionHandler(.allow)
              return
            }
          }
        }

       let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Page blocked!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
       ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
       present(ac, animated: true)

        decisionHandler(.cancel)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling this function before `decisionHandler(.cancel)` works fine:

```
func configureAlert() {

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Page blocked!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        
        if webView.isLoading == false {
            present(ac, animated: true)
            return
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i misunderstood the question. Try this out and let me know what you think.
Note: my websites array is included below as a note

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let url = navigationAction.request.url
    
    if let host = url?.host{
        //websites in websites array = ["apple.com", "bbc.com", "youtube.com", "tiktok.com", "yahoo.com", "ufc.com"]
        for website in websites{
            if (host.contains(website) && website != "tiktok.com") && (host.contains(website) && website != "youtube.com") {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
                return
            }else if (host.contains(website) && website == "tiktok.com") || (host.contains(website) && website == "youtube.com") {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Blocked website", message: "You are not allowed to access website", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss...", style: .cancel))
                present(alert, animated: true)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```